# "Skipping: Locked Class" issue during transform

Tags: enterprise-architect

I can't figure out why my MDA transform all of a sudden do not create any PDM out of my checked out LDM. It usually works as expected, but i now get this message during the transform progress: **"Skipping: Locked class - CLASS_NAME"**.
I use SVN for package versioning and made sure thtat the underlying XMI file for the package is unlocked in SVN. I have no idea about why all my classes are locked and no clue how to unlock these...

Comment: Maybe a project integrity check can fix things. I guess you don't have enabled security?

Comment: thanks for the comment... however, this didn't fix my lock issue.

Comment: I guess, this needs some interactive discussion. So you should elaborate on your Sparx thread.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use EA to checkout your packages. If you unlock it using SVN directly then EA doesn't know about that and will assume it is still checked in.

What you can do to fix that use the menu option **Package Control - Re-synch Status with VC Provider**

Comment: Thank you for this reply... however, re-synching all the packages in the branch with SVN doesn't seem to help. I've also checked out and then checked in the pacakges to be certain that EA IS the the one grabbing and then releasing the lock, but still no success. My tables are still being skipped due to locking. When I right-click->File Properties... my package, then i see that it doesn't define a lock owner. SVN also shows the package file as "not locked". So everything should be working... I don't know if it is related, but an integrity check shows my root package as an Orphaned object! why?!

Comment: Did you say you **checked-in** the package? In that case it is meant to be read-only. You have to **check-out** in order to change something to that package. But an integrity check (with fixing) might solve the problem as Thomas suggested.

Comment: Yes, i checked-in to trigger a lock release, but also checked out again in order to grab that package lock again. Sorry, if i was unclear. However, my understanding is that this is not relevant since i am using a another target package for the resulting transformation that is not locked. The integrity check/resolution didn't fix the problem. I am now left with no understanding as to why my classes are locked...